# How can I get rid of these artefacts?

Tags: mesh, artifacts

I have some curvatures on my mesh and I don't know how to get rid of those. I tried deleting some faces and recreate them but I got them back:
[image]

Comment: First thing disable the first option of the Subdivision Surface modifier (called On Cage) if you don't want your mesh to appear curvy, then show the wireframe again to see if it's ok (not sure if your problem is just the On Cage display?)

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

These are not artifacts, they are a display of how the base mesh is being deformed by a Subdivision Surface modifier. If you disable the modifier or go into edit mode, you will see the base mesh again. The visualization will not render to the final output. You can also turn off wireframe display wherever you enabled it to not see this.